# Django Is telling me table already exists on syncdb - can't figure out why

Tags: django, django-syncdb

Posted the model at http://pastebin.com/f609771cc

getting error: (yes it's windows)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'memorial_music' already exists")

scanned the whole project directory and memorial_music is only referenced twice

once as a table name and once as table name 'memorial_music_category'

this one has me scratching my head, any ideas?

Comment: forgot to mention: I delete all memorial_ tables before running syncdb... any ideas?

Comment: if you are on windows & using mysql,then most probably your problem is mysql.In windows mysql saves table names in small letter,by default.The solution is to name your model class in small letters or give the following at the end of the model class `class Meta:`
        `db_table = u'table_name' ` remember `table_name` should be small letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-mptt was the culprit

renamed table for memorial_music to memorial_music_library and everything went smooth

thank you django for manage.py sqlall appname

Answer (score 1):

Being a Django newbie I was having syncdb problems all the time.  Every time I would run it I would get Error ** table already exists.  After searching for answers with no avail and reading over and over again that syncdb : **"Creates the database tables for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS whose tables have not already been created.**".  I finally realized that when I did the initial python manage.py startapp UserData .... the capitalization of UserData was messing Django up (I'm using MYSQL).  If would have called it userData I wouldn't have had any problems.  I hope this helps someone with the same problem I had.

Edit ******

Maybe it wasn't a problem with the capitalization, I  think naming a table called userData in Django just doesn't work overall.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today.
Make sure all of your project folders names are lowercase. I think it would all work out.

Answer (score 0):

The complaint is that the table already exists **in the database**. Django cannot update an existing table. You either need to drop the table from the MySQL database, and syncdb again, or manually adjust the table schema to the model.