# Django syncdb behaving strangely with unicode strings

Tags: python, django, unicode, virtualenv, rhel

I'm going to apologize ahead of time for the length of this post. I just want to be sure I didn't leave any info out.

I have an application which uses django's ORM outside of a django app, which uses "syncdb" by calling `call_command('syncdb')` directly (note: I'm using a virtualenv for every scenario listed below).

My unit tests in the application try to setup a "test" django database using SQLite as the backend (whereas the production environment uses MySQL).

Each time one of the unit tests runs, it calls `call_command('syncdb')` using the same test django settings throughout each test.

I am able to run these unit tests on 2 different environments (one with Windows 7/Python 2.7.3, another with Mac OS X ML/Python 2.7.2). There are no issues at all with the tests; but these are relatively clean Python installs on both.

However, when I try to run this on a RHEL server, I get the following error, when the unit tests try to run syncdb:

> DatabaseError: table "my_app_mytable" already exists

After a lot of frustrating googling and debugging, I (think) I've eliminated the bugs reported [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9116) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283792/django-is-telling-me-table-already-exists-on-syncdb-cant-figure-out-why).

I did a lot of hacking around, and I think I have narrowed the problem down to this statement in [django's syncdb command file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py) (as crazy as that sounds) (line 59):

```
tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
```

I setup a `pdb.set_trace()` inside django's syncdb source on both environments to take a look. Here is what I found:

(Env that works)

```
(Pdb) tables
[u'my_app_mytable', u'my_app_myothertable']
```

Seems OK there. From the looks of the syncdb file, django uses the `tables` variable to check an app's models against what's already in the database.

(Env that doesn't work)

```
(Pdb) tables
[u'm\x00y\x00_\x00a\x00p\x00p\x00_\x00m\x00y\x00t\x00a\x00', u'm\x00y\x00_\x00a\x00p\x00p\x00_\x00m\x00y\x00o\x00t\x00']
```

Unless I'm just going crazy, I think this is making the following statement in django's source return false:

```
def model_installed(model):
        opts = model._meta
        converter = connection.introspection.table_name_converter
        return not ((converter(opts.db_table) in tables) or
            (opts.auto_created and converter(opts.auto_created._meta.db_table) in tables))
```

This method is called via `filter` a few lines after that definition, and it looks like it checks to see if `converter(opts.db_table)` is in the `tables` list. I ran them manually in both environments too:

(Env that works)

```
(Pdb) opts = all_models[0][1][0]._meta
(Pdb) converter = connection.introspection.table_name_converter
(Pdb) converter(opts.db_table) in tables
True
```

As you can see I (kind of) manually ran the `model_installed` function to see what `converter(opts.db_table)` returns, and it looks like a perfectly normal string on both environments. However:

(Env that doesn't work)

```
(Pdb) opts = all_models[0][1][0]._meta
(Pdb) converter = connection.introspection.table_name_converter
(Pdb) converter(opts.db_table) in tables
False
```

So it looks like since the `tables` variable is a list of crazy-looking crud on the broken environment, that method is falsely claiming that each model's table name isn't in the database, which gives me the original error I stated at the beginning.

Just to make sure I really wasn't going nuts, I also tried manually inserting the correct list to compare:

(Env that doesn't work)

```
(Pdb) converter(opts.db_table) in [u'my_app_mytable', u'my_app_myothertable']
True
```

Do I need to recompile Python on this environment? I read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253405/python-x00-filled-utf-32-string-from-cstringio) on stackoverflow, and found my broken environment was exhibiting weird behavior:

```
(myvirtualenv)[username@myserver]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 12 2012, 10:40:11)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import StringIO, cStringIO, sys
>>> StringIO.StringIO(u"fubar").getvalue()
u'fubar'
>>> cStringIO.StringIO(u"fubar").getvalue()
'fubar'
>>> cStringIO.StringIO(u"\u0405\u0406").getvalue()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535
>>> sys.byteorder
'little'
```

EDIT: OK, so I looked a little bit through the django source some more, and it looks like they're getting the table list this way:

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    "Returns a list of table names in the current database."
    # Skip the sqlite_sequence system table used for autoincrement key
    # generation.
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
        WHERE type='table' AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'
        ORDER BY name""")
    return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

So I connected to the sqlite file manually in the python interpreter, and ran that query:

(Env that doesn't work)

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/sqlite/file')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("""
... SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
... WHERE type='table' AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'
... ORDER BY name""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xb7557500>
>>> curs.fetchall()
[(u'c\x00c\x00_\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00s\x00_\x00c\x00c\x00',), (u'c\x00c\x00_\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00s\x00_\x00c\x00c\x00s',)]
```

So it looks like SQLite returns a UTF16-LE string for that query. On the working environment, it returned the following:

(Env that works)

```
>>> curs.fetchall()
[(u'my_app_mytable',), (u'my_app_myothertable',)]
```

Even without an encoding defined at the top, the "working" environment doesn't seem to have any trouble interpreting my `models` file and creating the tables appropriately. Is there some SQLite default setting that is causing this? Or is git converting the file to UTF-16LE on the broken environment, and sticking with UTF-8/ASCII in the working environment?

Comment: Where are you getting that broken `unicode` (which is actually UTF-16LE except it's in a `unicode`) from, and what does cStringIO have to do with it?

Comment: In the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10254962/1303955) it looks like the `cStringIO.StringIO(u"fubar").getvalue()` call returns a string like `'f\x00u\x00b\x00a\x00r\x00'`. I think I might have read the question wrong, is the behavior I showed in my question the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like my `sqlite3` module was acting up. I ended up reinstalling Red Hat's `sqlite-devel` package, recompiling Python 2.7.3, and then updating the executable in the virtualenv.

Seems to be working well now. Now when I run django's `get_table_list()` query, I get the following:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/sqlite/file')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("""
... SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
... WHERE type='table' AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'
... ORDER BY name""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xb7774ca0>
>>> curs.fetchall()
[(u'my_app_mytable',), (u'my_app_myothertable',)]
```

I made no changes to the sqlite file itself, so it seems this was an issue either with the `sqlite3` module, and/or my Python 2.7.3 installation.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem, same syncdb command executed successfully on one environment and not on other with same database imports and model.
Changing `call_command(syncdb)` to `os.system('python ' + |path|, 'manage.py syncdb'))` solved it for me.

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Your text editor has decided to save the file as UTF-16LE. [Put the following at the top of your source files, below the shebang:](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
# -*- coding: utf-16le -*-
```

Comment: I'm getting strange behavior with that encoding. I added it to the top of my source files but I'm getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` which seems to be pointing to the EOF newline.